# Plotting monthly difference of value in Excel

Tags: excel, graph, excel-formula

I'm having problem plotting a graph in Excel.

I was planning on plotting a graph for monthly difference of electric and gas that we consume every month.

Here is an example data:

[image]

What I want to have on each graph is how much was the difference from last month. Like instead of displaying 18/02/2018 7255, it will show 240 as it is the difference in usage from last month which was 7015, I want to know if our usages increase every month. Also that whenever I enter a new value from a new meter reading it will automatically update the graph that is on the other worksheet. Cause I plan to put the data on a different worksheet.

Is this possible?

Comment: Simplest way is to calculate the differences within hidden cells and then plot the results of the calculation.

Comment: I was thinking of that. I just thought there would an alternate formula.

Comment: Perhaps, but when you have such a simple and straightforward solution, it doesn't make much sense to invest efforts in search of a more _sophisticated_ alternative.

Comment: If it makes more sense, this spreadsheet is actually for a Multi-room letting business. The picture I sent is just for one House, and there's hundred more houses where it came from. Anyway thanks

Comment: Again, you could develop a MACRO that performs the calculations and feed the results to a PLOT, but this would be by far much more complex than the suggested approach. Anyway, good luck!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who answered!

I already figured out a simpler solution. I created 3 sheets in to the Workbook. Raw, Trend, and Graph.
I input the raw data in to the Raw, then have the difference computed on the Trend sheet. Similar to this:

```
=MAX(0,Raw!E66-Raw!D66)
```

I input max because we get negative values if there were no reading prior, and negative value would just ruin the line graph on the Graph sheet.

This is what the the Trend sheet looks like.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxChr.png)

The dates are also pulled out from the Raw sheet.
Basically, I just have to input the data on Raw sheet and and it will automatically update the other sheets in the Workbook.

**Cheers!**

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this with javascript, it is a powerful language that comes with a lot of powerful libraries for data visualization and data processing. It is can be an alternative to VBA and very useful in Excel.

I have written this example for you, I don't know which type of chart you wanted:

https://www.funfun.io/1/#/edit/5a97d6756f64c953db85bd65

I used an online editor with an embedded spreadsheet, so I can enter the data in the same format as in excel. To access the data in my code I use a JSON file, the short file underneath **setting**:

```
{
    "data": "=A1:F3"
}
```

Once you have access, you can use in your chart and create a beautiful, interactive and dynamic chart. There are many options to personalize your chart:

```
series: [{
        fillOpacity: 0.1,
        name: "electric",
        threshold: 0, //the y value where the negative and positve is seperate
        negativeColor: "#ff0000", // red
        color: "#00ff6e", // green
        type: 'area',
        data: electric
},{
        fillOpacity: 0.1,
        name: "gaz",
        threshold: 0, //the y value where the negative and positve is seperate
        negativeColor: "#ffe900", // yellow
        color: "#003bff", // bleu
        type: 'area',
        data: gas
}]
```

Once you have finished you can upload it in Excel by pasting the URL in the [Funfun Excel add-in](https://www.funfun.io/1/msaddin). Here is how it looks like with my example:

[image: final]

You can choose to hide a series by clicking on the label below the chart:

[image: electric]

And you can save your chart in many different format (.png, .pdf, ...):

[image: save]

To answer your question concerning the data scattered in different worksheet, you can use a javascript library called [SheetsJs](http://sheetjs.com/).

Hope this helps :)

**Disclosure : I’m a developer of Funfun.**